# Printing variable (which is a list) is printing "none" instead, in Python3

Tags: python

I have a variable "final" = lst1.append(num1)
I want to print final, but when I do it prints "None", rather than the value I want.

Code:

```
lst1 = [1,2,3,4]
num1 = 7
final = lst1.append(num1)

print ("The value for final is",final)
```

Here, I want it to print "The value for final is [1,2,3,4,7]", but instead it's printing "The value for final is None." What am I doing wrong? Is the problem here, or might I be returning a value wrong elsewhere in my code? (This code is just an small example for the error).

Also, is there a way to make it so when printing final, instead of it being a list, it prints it as a string? So 12347 instead of [1,2,3,4,7]

Help is appreciated!

Comment: `lst1.append(num1)` is done *in-place* and returns `None`. Do `print(lst1)` instead

Answer (score 0):

`lst.append(num1)` doesn't create new list - it adds element directly to `lst`. So it doesn't have to return anything (so it returns `None`).

You need `print(lst1)`

To create `final` and keep original `lst` do

```
final = lst1 + [num1]
```

It adds two list (so I have to use `[]` with `num1` to create second list) and assings it to `final`.

Or duplicate `lst` as `final` and `append()` to `final`

```
final = list[:]  # duplicate list
final.append(num1)
```

---

To print list of numbers you have to convert numbers to strings and concatenate it.

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]

txt = []

for x in lst:
    txt.append( str(x) )

print( "".join(txt) )
```

or shorter

```
print( "".join(str(x) for x in lst) )
```

Comment: That works! Thanks. Could you possibly help me understand why lst1 is now equal to lst1.append(num1), even though it was done when defining the final variable?

Comment: `lst1.append()` adds element directly to `lst1`. So it doesn't have to return value. If you want `final` and keep original `lst` (without `num1`) then use `final = lst1 + [num1]` It adds two lists and create new one which you assign to `final`